# How to transfer all the data from one JFrame to another JFrame through a button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Sorry I am new to Java so pardon my lack of knowledge. I have added in text fields, button and combo boxs in MainSystem JFrame. I want to enter data in Main System JFrame, get it's data and transfer through the button to the Receipt JFrame like a receipt. But I am unsure whether the data can be transferred for the combobox. Is there also any good option for layouts? My program layout is very spread out.  I also have no idea how to print out the combobox output.

This is my code below.

Main System (First JFrame)

```
  Receiptbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String name = namef.getText();
            String passport = passportf.getText();
            String contact = contactf.getText();
            String email = emailf.getText();
            String tourist = touristnumf.getText();
            String season = (String)SeasonBx.getSelectedItem();
            String region = (String)RegionBx.getSelectedItem();
            String meal = (String)MealBx.getSelectedItem();
            new Receipt();
       } 
   });
```

Receipt(The other JFrame):

```
public class Receipt extends JFrame
{
    //label names
    private JLabel namelbl;
    private JLabel passportlbl;
    private JLabel contactlbl;
    private JLabel emaillbl;
    private JLabel touristnumlbl;
    private JLabel seasonlbl;
    private JLabel regionlbl;

    //user input
    private JLabel rnamelbl;
    private JLabel rpassportlbl;
    private JLabel rcontactlbl;
    private JLabel remaillbl;
    private JLabel rtouristnumlbl;
    private JLabel rseasonlbl;
    private JLabel rregionlbl;
    private JLabel rmeallbl;

    //text fields name
    private JTextField namef;
    private JTextField passportf;
    private JTextField contactf;
    private JTextField emailf;
    private JTextField touristnumf;

    public Receipt()
    {
        //creating the labels
        namelbl = new JLabel("Full Name: ");
        passportlbl = new JLabel("Passport: ");
        contactlbl = new JLabel("Contact No: ");
        emaillbl = new JLabel("Email: ");
        touristnumlbl = new JLabel("Tourist No: ");
        seasonlbl = new JLabel("Season: "); 
        regionlbl = new JLabel("Region: ");

        //get data from text field after clicking button
        String name = namef.getText();
        String passport = passportf.getText();
        String contact = contactf.getText();
        String email = emailf.getText();
        String tourist = touristnumf.getText();
        Eventcollector ec = new Eventcollector(this, name, passport, contact, 
                                                email, tourist, season, region, meal);

        rnamelbl = new JLabel(name);
        rpassportlbl = new JLabel(passport);
        rcontactlbl = new JLabel(contact);
        remaillbl = new JLabel(email);
        rtouristnumlbl = new JLabel(tourist);

        setSize(700,600);
        //JFrame visibility and function to close on pressing the x 
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Event Collector:

```
public class Eventcollector extends EventObject
{
    private String name;
    private String passport;
    private String contact;
    private String email;
    private String touristnum;

    private String season;
    private String region;
    private String meal;

    //Accept info from source of event
    public Eventcollector(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public Eventcollector(Object source, String name, String passport, String contact, 
            String email, String touristnum, String season, String region, String meal)
    {
        super(source);

        this.name = name;
        this.passport = passport;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.email = email;
        this.touristnum = touristnum;
        this.season = season;
        this.region = region;
        this.meal = meal;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void getName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getpassport(){
        return passport;
    }

    public void getpassport(String passport){
        this.passport = passport;
    }

    public String getcontact(){
        return contact;
    }

    public void getcontact(String contact){
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getemail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void getemail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String gettouristnum(){
        return touristnum;
    }

    public void gettouristnum(String touristnum){
        this.touristnum = touristnum;
    }

    public String getseason(){
        return season;
    }

    public void getseason(String season){
        this.season = season;
    }

    public String getregion(){
        return region;
    }

    public void getregion(String region){
        this.region = region;
    }

    public String getmeal(){
        return meal;
    }

    public void getmeal(String meal){
        this.meal = meal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it too complicated or need more information?

Comment: What is the error you get? Also your formatting is a bit off.

Comment: Eventcollector ec = new Eventcollector(this, name, passport, contact, email, tourist, season, region, meal

Comment: That isn't an error, and it is the same thing you have posted in your question.

Comment: they say cannot find symbol for combo boxes.

Comment: How to improve my formatting?

Comment: Nothing in or around that line says combo box.  What is the actual symbol it cannot find.

Comment: First off, we don't need the source code for the event collector because the error isn't there. Does the add action listener code work?

Comment: @user2963724 please put your lines of code into the question and not into comment section. You can doing that by clicking on the edit link underneath your question. After that remove your comments.

Comment: @reporter they repeated the code that is in their question.

Comment: Maybe the symbol it is referring to is at eventcollector. But I was assuming the event collector will help to justify the data and also help to return the value to Receipt?

Comment: @user2963724 the problem appears to be that you are trying to reference variables from your `actionEvent` that don't exist outside of that method. You might need to paste your full Receipt class. Maybe even create your event collect in that method.

Comment: Well actually I follow this based on a video and not sure what is event collector is needed for .

Comment: It is probably for collecting the data, since you have a lot of data to pass around.

Comment: I have edited to show the receipt entire code excluding the imports. But I don't really know how to print out the combo box output so I didn't have that for now

Comment: Better, now the problem is obvious. You need to define the values. eg. `String season = (String)SeasonBx.getSelectedItem();`.

Comment: Thank you Matt! Now the error is gone! Although I have no idea whether the button is working cause I cannot fill in all the fields due to my disastrous layout and test whether the data from mainsystem can transfer to receipt . Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your action listener all of the values you are creating are forgotten/lost/ignore. You need to reference them in the action listener.

```
 Receiptbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String name = namef.getText();
        String passport = passportf.getText();
        String contact = contactf.getText();
        String email = emailf.getText();
        String tourist = touristnumf.getText();
        String season = (String)SeasonBx.getSelectedItem();
        String region = (String)RegionBx.getSelectedItem();
        String meal = (String)MealBx.getSelectedItem();
        Eventcollector ec = new Eventcollector(this, name, passport, contact, email, 
                                               tourist, season, region, meal);
   } 
});
```